# #define doubts...why this behaviour

Tags: c++, syntax, macros

I have defined the following max macro

```
#define max(a,b)(a>b?a:b);
```

Inside the main() I am doing the following

```
int t,a,b,c,d;

t=max(a,b)+max(c,d);
```

But the output is not as expected.t shows only the maximum value among a and b.
What could be the problem?

Comment: You should remove the ; in define. More information about macros here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function_002dlike-Macros.html#Function_002dlike-Macros

Comment: You should also [add parentheses](http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html) around the macro arguments in the macro body to avoid unexpected surprises.

Comment: You should also not define a macro with the same name as a standard library function; and not define a macro at all when there's a language-level construct (like an inline function) to do the same job without opening the door to a host of weird errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `;`. a `#define` is just text replacement.

You should also put `a` and `b` in parenthesis as a best practice. This one generally won't do much, since comparison operators take precedence over probably anything you might pass in, but say it were:

```
    #define mul(a, b) (a * b)
```

and then you say `mul(5-3, 10+2)` From this you'd expect the output to be 24 (2 * 12), but what actually gets executed is `5-3 * 10+2`, and using order of operations, this becomes `5-(3*10)+2`, so your answer would end up as -23 instead. If it had been defined as

```
    #define mul(a, b) ((a) * (b))
```

You wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

This will be like writing:

```
t = (a>b?a:b);+(a>b?a:b);
```

(Check the preprocessor output)

Remove the `;` from the *define*.